# Razor Asp.Net show textbox when checkbox is checked using jquery

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create a control with checkboxes that  when checked it will show a textbox , otherwise the textbox remains hidden. This is the code of the view, I'm trying to give this behavior using jquery but it doesn't work.

Here´s an example of the behavior expected
http://jsfiddle.net/v4fy2qjt/

View Code for checkbox control

```
 <div class="col-md-10 " style="padding-left:20px">


                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.disciplinas.Count; i++)
                {
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.disciplinas[i].Selected, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "myCheck" + i, @onclick = "addbox();" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.disciplinas[i].Text)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.disciplinas[i].Value)
                    <span>@Model.disciplinas[i].Text</span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.disciplinas[i].Quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "area" + i, @style = "display: none;" })

                    <br>
                }


            </div>
```

Jquery script

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        for (var i = 0; i <  @Model.disciplinas.Count; i++) {
            
                 document.getElementById('myCheck'+i).addEventListener("click", function () {

                     var el = document.getElementById('area'+i);

                     el.style.display = (el.style.display != 'none' ? 'none' : '');
                     
                 });
            

        }


    </script>


}
```

Comment: Your fiddle appears to work as expected.  What are you hoping to change?

Comment: Note you can do this with just css: http://jsfiddle.net/yLw0tm1b/

Comment: You can't use _model_ data like _@Model.disciplinas.Count_ in scripts